# "InstallShield Best Practices Validation Suite" is default feature in installshield 2012 Premier?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I was reading about features of Installshield Premier Edition, and i come accross this feature named "InstallShield Best Practices Validation Suite"...
Is this default feature or i need to do something to execute this feature...??

Answer (score 0):

Check out Tools > Options > Validation; there you can enable or disable various validation suites or individual tests.

Comment: Yes Michael Urman, I have seen all the validation tests, but i cannot decide which is better, or which one i should use for my Basic MSI Project...!!

If you can help further...??